# What is SSHA-512? How can OpenLDAP support it?

Tags: openldap

I have two OpenLDAP directory servers. One is a standard Zimbra OpenLDAP server. Accounts are with passwords that are using SSHA-512 hash method.

When I copy these accounts to a standard OpenLDAP server with sha2 module compiled and installed only SHA-512 is supported.

I cannot succesfully bind with accounts that have a SSHA-512 hash method. I can verify the password is correct with external LDAP browser but I cannot bind. the message is always that the credentials are invalid.
The authentication failed
    [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]

Is this a hash method specific for Zimbra OpenLDAP servers. It this hash method created by the Zimbra community?

Why would the Zimbra community use a non-standard hash method?

Where can we find this SSHA-512 hash method? So we can add this to standard OpenLDAP servers.

On the OpenLDAP website is
"OpenLDAP supports RFC 2307 passwords, including the {SHA}, {SSHA} and other schemes. Such passwords may be used as userPassword values and/or rootpw value. See (Xref) What are RFC 2307 hashed user passwords?. 
{SHA} and {SSHA} are RFC 2307 passwords schemes which use the SHA1 secure hash algorithm. The {SSHA} is the seeded varient. {SSHA} is recommended over other RFC 2307 schemes."

This information is not correct. I did create the slapd-sha2.so module as described for example here https://github.com/gcp/openldap/tree/master/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/sha2

But following this instruction will ensure not SSHA support, only SHA.

Comment: Most openldap servers use online configuration. Have you tried updating cn=module{0},cn=config with your new olcModuleLoad line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell OpenLDAP which scheme to use, in `slapd.conf` or the online configuration:

- In `slapd.conf` it is the `password-hash` entry.
- In the online configuration it is the `olcPasswordHash` entry in the top-level `olcGlobal` config object.

Set it to `{SSHA}`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I got here with a similar problem, and the solution was to load de module to support SSHA-2 algorithms. Include in the `slapd.conf` file the line:

```
moduleload pw-sha2.la
```

I hope this helps somebody ;-)

Comment: In my case it was `contrib-pw-sha2.la` but thanks for this vital clue.

Answer (score 1):

On newish systems where no *.conf exists, create a file `/tmp/hash` with contents:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
add: olcPasswordHash
olcPasswordHash: {SSHA}
```

Then:

```
apt install ldap-utils
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/hash
```

Comment: SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
 additional info: <olcPasswordHash> no valid hashes found